# Pandas Column Names of MultiIndex DataFrame - strange behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I observed some strange pandas behavior with MultiIndex dataFrames.columns

Construction a MultiIndex dataframe:

```
a=[0,.25, .5, .75]
b=[1, 2, 3, 4]
c=[5, 6, 7, 8]
d=[1, 2, 3, 5]
df=pd.DataFrame(data={('a','a'):a, ('b', 'b'):b, ('c', 'c'):c, ('d', 'd'):d})
```

produces this dataFrame

```
      a  b  c  d
      a  b  c  d
0  0.00  1  5  1
1  0.25  2  6  2
2  0.50  3  7  3
3  0.75  4  8  5
```

Creating a new variable with a subset of the original dataFrame

```
df1=df.copy().loc[:,[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]]
```

produces like expected:

```
      a  b
      a  b
0  0.00  1
1  0.25  2
2  0.50  3
```

but accessing the column names of this new dataFrame produces some unexpected output:

```
print df1.columns

MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd'], [u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])
```

so ('b', 'b') and ('c', 'c') is still contained.

In contrast

```
print df1.columns.tolist()
```

returns like expected:

```
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
```

can anybody explain me the reason for this behavior??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html) what is new function in `0.20.0` version.

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-shown-levels).

```
print (df1.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])

print (df1.columns.remove_unused_levels())
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 1], [0, 1]])
```